# Is there a way to disable SCPSolver's output?

Tags: java, system.out, disable, scpsolver

I'm writing an application in Java that uses the following external library: SCPSolver (link: http://scpsolver.org/).

The library appears to be a wrapper for a c library and prints some information on the standard out. My problem is I'd like my application to have a clean output: I'm looking for a way to either

a. clear the console, which might be either a system (windows) console or eclipse's console; or

b. straight up prevent the library from printing on the output.

**Regarding point a:**

I've tried both using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

and

```
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
```

and neither work.

I've tried printing "\b" characters but to no avail. In all these cases, I get gibberish in the output.

**Regarding point b:**

I've tried redirecting System.out to a new PrintStream, but it doesn't work. That's most likely because the library is a wrapper to a c library, and the c library prints bypass java's System.out. Thus I'm not really sure this approach would work, as I have no control over what the library does. I've looked in the documentation for a way to disable the output, and haven't found anything useful yet.

**A possibly useful note:**
Calling

```
System.out.close();
```

before asking the solver to solve an LP problem prevents the output from being displayed. Of course, the problem then is: I have no more stream to stdout to print to. Maybe a solution could be getting another stream to the same console? Though I have no idea how to do this.

**In short:**

The call to lpw.solve() is what prints the undesired output:

```
LPWizard lpw = new LPWizard();

// ...

LPSolution solution = lpw.solve();
```

Current output is:

> GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65 4 rows, 4 columns, 8 non-zeros
>         0: obj =  0.000000000e+000 inf =  2.700e+001 (4)
>         3: obj =  1.350000000e+001 inf =  0.000e+000 (0) OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND x1: 4.0 x2: 2.5 x3: 7.0 x4: 0.0

I'd expect it to instead be none.

Comment: I tried the following:
`PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out));
System.out.close();
LPSolution solution = lpw.solve();
System.setOut(o);`
Unfortunately it doesn't work: when the System.out stream is closed, the fd for stdout is also closed, resulting in the o stream being closed as well...

Comment: In the end, it seems modifying the source code and recompiling is the only way. Unfortunately, I get the following error while building: `D:\All Users\Matt\Documenti\scpsolver\externaltools\glpk>gcc -fPIC -shared -o glpkjni_x64.dll glpk_jni.o lpx.o C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll -Wl,--kill-at lib\win_64\libglpk.a lib\win_64\libltdl.dll.a -lm lib\win_64\libz.a -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19"\include\ -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19"\include\win32\
lib\win_64\libglpk.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.